# Unfortunately myandroidapps has stopped

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android apps development. I successfully signed my apps and installed on my phone Android Ver. 4.1.2. The codes below are my codes. May I know what is wrong? Thanks guys/girls :)

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFlashlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Torch" />   </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mkyong.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //flag to detect flash is on or off
    private boolean isLighOn = false;

    private Camera camera;

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);

        Context context = this;
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
            return;
        }

        camera = Camera.open();
        final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (isLighOn) {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isLighOn = false;

                } else {

                    Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                    camera.setParameters(p);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isLighOn = true;

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**myandroidapps Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FlashLightActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>   </manifest>
```

Comment: Post your LogCat...so we can help you.

Comment: I tried LogCat but it is not working. My apps open up and then the whole screen becomes black. Then, the error "Unfortunately myandroidapps has stopped". Nothing is shown on LogCat

Comment: Then you will definately have something in LogCat! Make sure you don't have a filter set..you should see *something*.

Comment: Sometimes there are problems in the logcat viewer in eclipse. To get the logcat go to command prompt and give "adb logcat" command and redirect the output to a file. Then check for exception which would have been thrown and post the relevant portion here.

Answer (score 2):

you forget to declare `MainActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.  add it as:

```
    ....
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    ....
    </application>
    ....
```

Comment: Hi all, not working. I made changes to **.FlashLightActivity** in AndroidManifest.xml to the following code:    <application
       
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="false">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="**.MainActivity**" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>